# Python Converts the backslash followed by numbers into Unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, backslash, rawstring

I have a string which is a Windows path returned by another function. The function returns the path with a single backslash within it. Here  I can't using raw string conversion to a variable. `re.escape(path)` does not work either. `path.replace('\','\\')` throws `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`
The function returns a path something like `"D:\Data\201909\Foo\20190927c\Files"` which gets coverted into `"D:\\Data\ü909\\Foo\x8190927c\\Files"`

`path` can be assumed as the variable containing the value returned by the function.
Could you please suggest me a solution for this.
Thanks Much !

Comment: You can use `r'<path>'`

Comment: @AkshatSood The path is retuurned in variable.

Comment: I found out the solution . `path=r"{}" .format(path) ` worked

Answer (score -1):

The below solution worked for me.
`path = r"{}" .format(path)`
where new variable path is the converted raw string.

Comment: Raw strings only work with literal strings.  `r"{}" == "{}"`.  Update your question with a reproducible example showing *exactly* what is in your variable and what is wrong with it.